# SPARQL: Retrieving resources linked by multiple properties

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am having a bit of trouble while trying to retrieve all the IRI linked to a resources using a list of property.

In my case, I have a list of resources from the BNF and I would like to find, for each of them, all the resources associated with them using one of the subproperties of `<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/contributor>` .

If i search for all the subPropertyOf of `<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/contributor>` I retrieve the 525 properties I am considering:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {
  

  ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/contributor> .
}
```

However, if I try to find resources associated with them with the following query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?p ?contributor WHERE {
  
   ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/contributor> .
  <http://data.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb322025612#Expression> ?p ?contributor 
}
```

I do not have any results...What I am doing wrong?

Endpoint is here: https://data.bnf.fr/sparql if someone else wants to try

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong, there is a bug in the data ... the properties returned by the first query do all follow the URI pattern `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/roles/r{NUMBER}/` - the main issue here is, the URIs end with a slash `/` - this is clearly unusual and not what the instance data is using. Your example entitiy does have such a role for sure, but the URI is `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/roles/r70` - without the trailing slash. Long story short, the data owner has to fix the property hierarchy triples.

Comment: indeed, I just noticed it myself now. Thank you for pointinig it out! I thought I was doing some errors that I could not see...I am going to write to the BNF and see if I can get the uri fixed. In the meanwhile i will try to download the data and fix thing locally. Thank again.